# prevent normal user to uninstall my windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have created one windows service, and install it in my computer successfully now i want to prevent normal user to uninstall my service ,it means someone needs to uninstall my windows service from there computer then need special credential to uninstall that service

can any one suggest any idea how can i do this

the structure of my service start method is something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TimeClockGetDataService");
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (args.FirstOrDefault())
                {
                    case "/install":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                    case "/uninstall":
                        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                        break;
                    case "/interactive":
                        using (TimeClockPuchDataGetService service = new TimeClockPuchDataGetService())
                        {
                            service.OnStart(args);
                            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the program");
                            Console.Read();
                            service.Stop();
                            //service.GetDataFromPunchingMachin();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Supported arguments:");
                        Console.WriteLine(" /install      Install the service");
                        Console.WriteLine(" /uninstall    Uninstall the service");
                        Console.WriteLine(" /interactive  Run the service interactively (on the console)");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Run(new TimeClockPuchDataGetService());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: bcoz it is like monitoring service that monitor user log if i allow x user to uninstall that service i cant get log of that system

Comment: Seems like you want a group policy

Comment: Normal users can't uninstall services. Don't you have to be local admin for that?

Comment: can i set some fix credential ?,if any body want to uninstall that service they need that credential

Comment: Local admins can uninstall services. Full stop. If the "threat vector" is people who already have local admin access, you've already lost. As jgauffin says, non-admin users cannot uninstall services. So there's nothing to do here as soon as you accept that you cannot stop local admins from doing anything *they* want on the box (ultimately, in the "battle" between programs and users, Microsoft let users ultimately win. This is a good thing)